# Filter Data from Database

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

I want to filtter data from access database and show it to datagridview. Given below is the data from database.

```
ADMISSIONNO  STUDENTNAME  STUDENTCLASS  STUDENTSECTION    DUE    CLASSID
   111         nitish           6               a         1477     33
   112         ravi             6               a         1400     33
   113         raj              7               b         5000     35
   111         nitish           6               a         1200     33
   112         ravi             6               a         900      33
   113         raj              7               b         1000     35
   111         nitish           6               a         500      33
   112         ravi             6               a         300      33
   113         raj              7               b         600      35
```

i want a query to filtter the above data as when user select the CLASSID(33),
output should be like among the same ADMISSIONNO which is the lowest due, display that row. The output should be

```
ADMISSIONNO   STUDENTNAME  STUDENTCLASS  STUDENTSECTION   DUE
   111         nitish           6               a         500
   112         ravi             6               a         300
```

the query which i am using is:

```
 OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand();
            command1.Connection = connection;
            string clas = "SELECT FeeData.ADMISSIONNO, FeeData.STUDENTNAME, FeeData.DUE, FeeData.STUDENTCLASS, FeeData.STUDENTSECTION, FeeData.CLASSID FROM FeeData WHERE(((FeeData.DUE) > '0') AND((FeeData.CLASSID) = "+ClassID+")) ";
            command1.CommandText = clas;
            OleDbDataReader reader = command1.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
              //read the data
            }
```

After running this query the data which i am getting is:

```
ADMISSIONNO  STUDENTNAME  STUDENTCLASS  STUDENTSECTION    DUE    CLASSID
   111         nitish           6               a         1477     33
   112         ravi             6               a         1400     33
   111         nitish           6               a         1200     33
   112         ravi             6               a         900      33
   111         nitish           6               a         500      33
   112         ravi             6               a         300      33
```

I guess query is not correct. Please help me out!!

Comment: You need GROUP BY with MIN scalar function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need GROUP BY and MIN on your fields to group records according to all your conditions and then select the record with the minimum value.

```
string clas = @"SELECT f.ADMISSIONNO, f.STUDENTNAME, f.STUDENTCLASS,
                       f.STUDENTSECTION, f.CLASSID, MIN(f.DUE)
               FROM FeeData AS f 
               WHERE f.DUE > 0 AND f.CLASSID = @id
               GROUP BY f.ADMISSIONNO, f.STUDENTNAME, f.STUDENTCLASS,
                        f.STUDENTSECTION, f.CLASSID";
```

Notice also that you NEVER concatenate strings to create an sql command but always use a parameterized query

```
command1.CommandText = clas;
command1.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = ClassID;
OleDbDataReader reader = command1.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.
You need to write `GROUP BY` in the query.
Just write this.

---

```
SELECT *
FROM FeeData
WHERE(((FeeData.DUE) > '0') AND((FeeData.CLASSID) = "+ClassID+"))
GROUP BY ADMISSIONNO'
```